# How to update packages/SDK for Buildfire App through Buildfire?

Tags: facebook, sdk, package, buildfire

I am wondering how to update packages through Buildfire for an app. Needing to update to the latest Facebook SDK that supports iOS 14 and according to Facebook docs you can update 2 ways with either SPM or Cocoapods. I have looked everywhere and am not sure how to determine which is being used in Buildfire or where/how to update it in the Developer portal/Control Panel in Buildfire.

Comment: Were you able to update Facebook SDK? We configured Facebook marketing from control panel as suggested in accepted answer but we are still getting error related to SKAdNetwork while configuring ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done through the BuildFire Control Panel.
[image]

Here is the link to the help article https://learn.appdocumentation.com/en/articles/5360188-app-marketing-ios-and-android-setup